# AWK from text with modification

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have the following file:

```
hello there. let's try&ACCT=1&bla bla bla&EX=1118&anything ss &SERIAL=1011&DEAL=NO
BLA BLA BLA&TOM=1&ACCT=2&LSLSLSLSL&none=1&EX=1218&lord=1&ok=1&SERIAL=201&flag=non
```

from which I need to extract the field values of `ACCT=`, `EX=` and `SERIAL=`  so that the output becomes:

```
1,11/18,1011
2,12/18,201
```

where `EX` is always a 4 digit number where I want to insert a `/` as the middle character.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, I'm asking that question because i don't know where to start. or to help in case if you willing to help or just leave it. My Pleasure

Comment: @Fabby to make it easy to understood the point, let's say we are looking to locate words of `ACCT=` , `EX=` AND `SERIAL=` and grep the numbers after `=` and before `&`

Comment: @Fabby it's a real-life example on my question. We can use `awk` to on each line for the words and grep values between `=` and `&`

Comment: @Fabby `EX=` 4 digits And `SERIAL=`  3 or 4 digits and `ACCT=` 15 OR 16 Digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample input, which I placed into a file called test.in, the following awk command should give you the output you desire.

```
awk -F\& '{for (i=1; i<+NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^ACCT=/) {acct=$i; sub(/^ACCT=/, "", acct)} if ($i ~ /^EX=/) {ex=$i; sub(/^EX=/, "", ex); sub(/^[0-9][0-9]/, "&/", ex)} if ($i ~ /^SERIAL=/) {serial=$i; sub(/^SERIAL=/, "", serial)}} printf("%s,%s,%s\n", acct, ex, serial)}' test.in
```

What this does is it treats the & as a field separator.  It then processes each field in a given line by checking if that field starts with ACCT=, EX= or SERIAL=.  If that field is found, that field is assigned to the appropriate variable.  The sub command is then used to remove the start of that variable. This just gives you the value associated with that key.

Since you require a slash (/) after the first 2 digits in the EX key, that is the other sub for EX.  The ampersand (&) is a back-reference that picks up those first 2 digits.

Once all of the fields have been processed, it prints out the values found in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below method and its worked fine as expected

```
 k=`awk -F "&" '{print NF}' test.txt | sort | uniq| head -1`
for ((h=1;h<=$k;h++)); do awk -v h="$h" -F "&" '$h ~ /ACCT/ || $h ~ /EX/ || $h ~ /SERIAL/{print $h}' test.txt; done
```

output

```
ACCT=1
ACCT=2
EX=1118
SERIAL=1011
EX=1218
SERIAL=201
```

Comment: Why doesn't your output match the OP's expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` & `cat` i achieved  a stage of solution :)

```
sed 's/.*ACCT=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' test > 1
sed 's/.*EX=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' test > 2
sed 's/.*SERIAL=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' test > 3
```

**THEN**

```
paste 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also this simple step-by-step `sed` approach:

```
sed -r 's/^.*ACCT=//; s/&.*EX=/,/; s/&.*SERIAL=/,/; s/&.*$//; s/,(..)(..),/,\1\/\2,/' file
1,11/18,1011
2,12/18,201
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below steps and it worked fine

```
 for i in {1..9}; do awk -v i="$i" -F "&" '$i ~ /ACCT/ || $i ~ /SERIAL/{print $i}' p_final.txt; done | awk -F "=" '{print $NF}' >final.txt

for i in {1..9}; do awk -v i="$i" -F "&" '$i ~ /EX/{print $i}' p_final.txt; done| awk -F "=" '{print $NF}'| awk '{print substr($1,1,2)"/"substr($1,3,2)}' >>final.txt


cat final.txt  | sed -n '1~2p' | tr "\n" ","| sed 's/,$//g' | sed  "s/.*/&\n/g"  >output.txt
 cat final.txt  | sed -n '2~2p' | tr "\n" ","| sed 's/,$//g' | sed  "s/.*/&\n/g"  >>output.txt


[root@praveen_linux_example ~]# cat output.txt
1,1011,11/18
2,201,12/18
[root@praveen_l
```